# How to get the value of a callback outside the upload function of the Vimeo class?

Tags: asynchronous, callback, nestjs, vimeo-api

I'm very new to js and I'm learning Nestjs. I'm building an API to work with the Vimeo API using their Vimeo lib. To upload a video, the Vimeo class has a method called upload:

```
upload(
        file: string | File,
        params: object,
        completeCallback: UriCallback,
        progressCallback: ProgressCallback | undefined,
        errorCallback: ErrorCallback,
    ): void;
    upload(
        file: string | File,
        completeCallback: UriCallback,
        progressCallback: ProgressCallback | undefined,
        errorCallback: ErrorCallback,
    ): void;
```

On my service, I used it like:

```
async uploadVideo(@Body() video: UploadVideoDto): Promise<string> {
    let videoUri: string;
    this.client.upload(
      video.pathToFile,
      {
        name: video.name,
        description: video.description,
      },
      function (uri) {
        console.log(uri);
        videoUri = uri;
      },
      function (bytesUploaded, bytesTotal) {
        console.log(bytesUploaded, bytesTotal);
      },
      function (error) {
        throw new Error(error);
      },
    );
    return videoUri;
  }
```

The `function (uri) { console.log(uri) }`  is the callback function when the upload finishes and it gives the uri that the video was uploaded to. I tried to get it on my controller, like this:

```
 @Post('/upload')
  async upload(@Body() video: UploadVideoDto) {
    await this.appService.uploadVideo(video).then(function (uri): void {
      console.log(uri);
    });
  }
```

The problem is that the console.log(uri) always prints undefined. How can I get that callback return from my service to my controller?

Comment: (this is not related with your question but) the `@Body()` in your service's parameter won't work as you expected. They are just for nestjs controllers. Learn about typescript decoratos: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html

Comment: You're absolutely right! I've written and re-written those two files and got it mixed up, but thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if `uploadVideo` should return a Promise that resolves to an string (the `uri`), it could be like this:

```js
async uploadVideo(video: UploadVideoDto): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {

    this.client.upload(
      video.pathToFile,
      {
        name: video.name,
        description: video.description,
      },
      function (uri) {
        resolve(uri)
      },
      function (bytesUploaded, bytesTotal) {
        console.log(bytesUploaded, bytesTotal);
      },
      function (error) {
        reject(error)
      },
    );

  })
}
```

Learn about JS [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await) feature.